# Inverted Sum of a Number -- Haskell

Tags: haskell, math, functional-programming

I have the following function in Haskell:

```
invertedSum :: Integer -> Integer
invertedSum n = n + (read . reverse . show) n
```

I need to know the number of sums that must be made in order for the number to be capicua. That is to say,

```
invertedSum 1999 = 11990   (1999+9991)
invertedSum 11990 = 21901 
invertedSum 21901 = 32813
invertedSum 32813 = 64636
invertedSum 64636 = 128282
invertedSum 128282 = 411103
invertedSum 411103 = 712217

isCapicua :: Integer -> Bool
isCapicua n | show n == (reverse . show) n   = True
            | otherwise                      = False

isCapicua 712217 == True
```

So, I want to generate the following list, but I don't know how.

```
sumUpToCapicua 1999 = [11990, 21901, 32813, 64636, 128282, 411103, 712217]
```

`genericLength (sumUpToCapicua 1000000079994144385) == 259`

Comment: BTW, please don't call this “inverted”. The inverse of a number is, depending on context, either its additive or multiplicative inverse (i.e. the negative or reciprocal), which are a much more useful quantities. Reversing the decimal digits of a number is something completely unnatural and base-dependent, which has no real practical uses.

Comment: Side note: things equivalent to `if x == y then True else False` are also equivalent to `x == y`. `(==)` returns a `Bool` already. It's not some special syntax that only works in conditionals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a function `invertedSum` with the type `Integer -> Integer`. If I understand the question correctly, you'd like to apply it multiple times, starting with a particular `Integer` (e.g. `1999`).

You could use `iterate` for that purpose. It has the type:

```
Prelude> :t iterate
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

In other words, it'll take any function `a -> a`, as well as an initial value `a`, and produce an *infinite* list of `a` values.

In your case, `invertedSum` has the type `Integer -> Integer`, and the initial value you'd like to use (e.g. `1999`) would also be of the type `Integer`, so it all fits: `a` would be `Integer`.

Try using `invertedSum` and e.g. `1999` with `iterate`. Be aware that this produces an *infinite* list, so if you experiment with this in GHCi, you probably want to use e.g. `take 10` to cap the number of values generated.

Comment: So, could I do  `dropWhile (isCapicua) (iterate (invertedSum) n)` for solving?

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar What would happen if `isCapicua` never returns `False`?

Comment: The list is infinite

Comment: Why `isCapicua` never returns `False`?

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar I don't know, I haven't analysed the problem formally. Have you tried `dropWhile (isCapicua) (iterate (invertedSum) n)` with various input? Can you guarantee that, for any `n`, it eventually returns a value?

Comment: @MarkSeemann the algorithm "usually" converges, but there are notable exceptions (196 is the well known one).

Comment: Yes, I know it but I do `dropWhile (isCapicua) (iterate (invertedSum) n) == []`  I don't why.

Comment: And if put `takeWhile` is an infinit list.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar - You probably want to be doing a dropWhile looking for not isCapicua, and then the head of the remaining list will be your isCapua.  Likewise, if you want to know how this transforms, you could do a takeWhile not isCapicua, and that would get you all of the steps to get to the palindrome.